# How to check continuation of an existing character of a new character?

Tags: utf-8

If you’re reading a file encoded as UTF-8, and you read a byte, how can you
determine if that byte is a continuation of an existing character, rather than the
beginning of a new character?

Comment: Again, read how UTF-8 bytes are encoded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A byte is a UTF-8 continuation byte if the binary value of the byte is `10xxxxxx` (*x* can be 0 or 1).  Initial UTF-8 bytes follow these patterns:

```
0xxxxxxx - start (and end) of 1-byte sequence
110xxxxx - start of 2-byte sequence (followed by one continuation byte)
1110xxxx - start of 3-byte sequence (followed by two continuation bytes)
11110xxx - start of 4-byte sequence (followed by three continuation bytes)
```